# How can I anchor the bottom of a gradient to the container that it fills in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to paint a gradient half-way up the canvas, so that the gradient covers the top half.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to make the gradient line up with the 
'container' (the shape controlled by `fillRect()`) - When I push the container up to the proper position, the gradient stays anchored to the bottom of the canvas; not the bottom of the container that it's filling.

The bottom of the gradient should begin at the bottom of the container that it fills, not the bottom of the canvas. How can I achieve this?

```js
//not sliding gradient container upward
function paintC1() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-1');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var height = canvas.height;
  var width = canvas.width;
  var grd = context.createLinearGradient(width, 0, width, height);
  grd.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(0,174,239,0)');
  grd.addColorStop(0.85, 'rgba(0,174,239,0.6)');
  grd.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,174,239,1)');
  context.fillStyle = grd;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

/* for comparison */

//sliding gradient container up
function paintC2() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-2');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var height = canvas.height;
  var width = canvas.width;
  var grd = context.createLinearGradient(width, 0, width, height);
  grd.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(0,174,239,0)');
  grd.addColorStop(0.85, 'rgba(0,174,239,0.6)');
  grd.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,174,239,1)');
  context.fillStyle = grd;
  context.fillRect(0, -50, width, height);
}

paintC1();
paintC2();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas-1" style="width:250px; height:500; border-style:solid; float:left; margin-right:10px;"></canvas>

<canvas id="canvas-2" style="width:250px; height:500; border-style:solid; float:left; margin-right:10px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: The bottom of the gradient already begin at the bottom of the container that it fills

Comment: @InvernoMuto No it isn't. I added a contrast example for you in the snippet to demonstrate.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly what you need to do is shorten the height of your `createLinearGradient()`. The way you have it now the gradient is being created to match the size of the canvas.

Comment: right, seem that the coordinates of gradient is relative of canvas

Comment: So, you doesn't have to draw rect with negative Y, you have to translate the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient fill is relative to canvas, not to element, so to achieve your task you should do something like this.

```
 var grd = context.createLinearGradient(width, -50, width, height -50);
```

otherwise you have to translate the context:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 30);
var sampleW = 100;
var sampleH = 30;
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(0,174,239,0)');
gradient.addColorStop(0.85, 'rgba(0,174,239,0.6)');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,174,239,1)');

var translations= [[30, 150],[100, 110],[170, 70],[240, 30]];

context.font = '12px verdana bold';
for (var i = 0; i < translations.length; i++) {
  var t= translations[i];
  context.save();
  // gradient is defined at the origin,
  // so we have to move the origin
  context.translate(t[0], t[1])
  context.fillStyle = gradient;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, sampleW, sampleH);
  context.strokeRect(0, 0, sampleW, sampleH);
 
  context.restore();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```